# regex email validation length

Tags: java, regex, email

I have the following regex for email validation in java

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-    9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])$
```

I want to check that email shouldnt exceed 255 characters, how do i do that?
Thanks

Comment: *"I want to check that email shouldnt exceed 255 characters, how do i do that?"* Separately.

Comment: cant you just use String.length() ??

Comment: Why not just use `emailAddress.length()<=255` ?

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple.

`if (yourString.length() <= 255 && yourString.matches(YOUR_REGEX))`

Comment: *Technically*, you want `<= 255`. The OP said the length shouldn't *exceed* 255 characters.

Answer (score 4):

This regex works for all the possible email patterns and for different domains.

```
abc@gmail.com
abc.de@gmail.in
abc.15@gmail.com
abc@def.technology
```

The respective regex is :

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: @KRUPA Super... Works well for validating an email pattern for different domains

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regexp for this other than for a simple sanity check (does it have a '@' and something that looks like a TLD, perhaps), and a simple string length check.

The regexp for a fully compliant mail address is [immense](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). You don't really want to go there.

Answer (score 1):

If you really would like to extend the Regexp concerning the length, you may prepend a lookahead expression like this:

```
^(?=.{255}$)
```

Result:

```
=> ^(?=.{255}$)[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+............
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete Zhonk response:
^(?=.{6,255}$)[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,6}